# How should I inject a factory into a class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, mocking, factory-pattern

I can't use a DI container, so I am stuck with using a factory. Should I use a package level setter or a public setter or a package level field?

As common as factories are, I haven't found the most accepted answer to this problem. During unit testing, I want to be able to mock out this factory.

Comment: but why would i want to inject the factory via the constructor? i'd be forcing the clients to have a factory on hand.... that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: it would be instantiated where it is declared and then only injected when testing.

Comment: You don't need to inject the factory, as it can be mocked as is. That said, the best "solution" is to not have the factory at all...